# Prevent iOS in app purchase being shared between devices

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I intend my app to gain access to my server after the in-app purchase is complete. This access requires real work, and data &  traffic ($$).

A typical client might own anywhere up to a couple of hundred devices (and I assume on one account, for their simplicity).
Thus I only get the one payment across many, many devices interacting with the server.

I'm not trying to be stingy - but can I prevent multiple devices sharing the same purchase (in my case server access)?
Or do I implement another method for selling access?

Comment: I hope there really is a day dedicated to things being thrown out of windows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement another method. Apple's guide explicitly states that:

> Users can restore products that they previously purchased—for example, to bring content they’ve already paid for onto their new phone.

If the same iTunes account is associated with more than one device then Apple requires any purchases to be available on all those devices.

Answer (score 0):

@Tommy is correct - regarding non-consumable IAPs. However, you could implement a non-recurring subscription in-app purchase instead and give each device a unique identifier. When the user attempts to access the server, you could see if that identifier is in your database (if the user has purchased the IAP), and determine whether or not they need to purchase a subscription. Even though you may not want a subscription-based service, you could probably make a membership for a very long period of time like 10 years (it's not required to be selected in iTunes Connect) and handle it that way. Only issue is that you need to figure out a way to give each device a unique ID that won't change.

Comment: I'm under the impression that we are prohibited from uniquely identifying any particular device..?

Comment: You can uniquely identify a device for your app via `identifierForVendor`, but this value can change if a user deletes and re-installs your app on the same device, in which case they would be locked out of the subscription.  Additionally, subscriptions must comply with the same clause in the other answer - they should be restorable on any device linked to the iTunes account.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the @Tommy answer, in the February 3, 2014 version of Apple's `Getting Started with In-App Purchase on iOS and OS X` it says:

> There are a handful of important guidelines to keep in mind as you design your application:
>   - You must make your In-App Purchase items available to all of the devices registered to a user

and

> Users view the items they purchase as theirs to keep and permanent. Therefore be sure
>   purchased items are available in all instances of your app running on all the devices the user
>   owns, even after your app is deleted from a device, reinstalled, or downloaded to a new device.

and

> For Non-Renewing Subscriptions, [blah, blah, blah].. 
>   Additionally, your application must include a mechanism to deliver the purchased Non-
>   Renewing Subscription In App Purchase to all iOS devices owned by a single user.

Looks like there is no way to restrict items to a single device :(